# uwsgi won't start celery daemon

Tags: python, flask, celery, uwsgi

I have a flask application that runs under uwsgi.  I'm trying to add celery as a smart-attach-daemon to handle long running and periodic tasks.

my uwsgi config looks like this:

```xml
<uwsgi>
<plugin>python</plugin>
<socket>/run/uwsgi/app/factory.XXXX.com/factory.XXXX.com.socket</socket>
<pythonpath>/srv/www/factory.XXXX.com/XXXXweb</pythonpath>
<callable>app</callable>
<app mountpoint="/">

    <script>run</script>

</app>
<master/>
<smart-attach-daemon>/tmp/celery.pid celery -A app.celery worker --pidfile=/tmp/celery.pid</smart-attach-daemon>
<processes>4</processes>
<harakiri>60</harakiri>
<reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
<cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
<stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
<max-requests>2000</max-requests>
<limit-as>512</limit-as>
<reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
<reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
<buffer-size>32768</buffer-size>
<no-orphans/>
<catch-exceptions/>
<vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

When I run the celery worker from the command line, it works great but I can't figure out how to get uwsgi to launch it.

My uwsgi config from the webhost is in XML but all the examples I can find are in .ini format so I'm guessing at syntax.

When I start with the above config, the flask app starts fine but not celery.  The log file shows no errors.

Comment: are you sure you are not running an obsolete uWSGI version without smart daemons support ? (remember only 1.4.x and 2.x are still supported and considered stable)

Comment: Yes.  Nice catch.  I didn't realize the ubuntu uwsgi version was so old.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.